# Xamarin webview geolocation oreo POSITION_UNAVAILABLE

Tags: android, xamarin

I have a webview that asks the user for its location. I wrote a request for permission of geolocation, it works. But it works only on sdk version below 8.0. On a newer version, javascript produces an error with the code `POSITION_UNAVAILABLE`.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Did you solved the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Cause:**

In an effort to reduce power consumption, Android 8.0 (API level 26) limits how frequently background apps can retrieve the user's current location.So the old methodthat just used locationManager to get the current location is no longer available in the background.

**Solution:**

I suggestion that you can use some map sdk.Such as [google Map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/location).